# Using MATLAB to write String values into Excel spreadsheet via ActiveX protocol.. found a problem

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

I'm using MATLAB 2017a and have been using `xlswrite` in the past to perform this operation. The problem I ran into was with execution speed and I was looking for a better way. So, I decided to use `actxserver` and write data using `get(obj)` from MATLAB and `Range.Value` from ActiveX. Here's what the code looks like:

```
e = actxserver('Excel.Application);
eWorkbook = e.Workbooks.Add;
e.Visible = 1;
eSheets = e.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
eSheet1 = eSheets.get('Item',1);
eSheet1.Activate;
A = ["Str1";"Str2";"Str3";];
eActivesheetRange = get(e.Activesheet, 'Range', 'A1:A3');
eActivesheetRange.Value = A;
```

This inocuous bit of code does not execute, nor does it throw a warning or error message.. Nothin'. In my mind, the `eActivesheetRange` evaluates to: `Range("A1:A3")` on the ActiveX side. Interestingly, if I replace

```
A = ["Str1";"Str2";"Str3";];
```

with

```
A = char(["Str1";"Str2";"Str3";]);
```

then the program writes the A char array to each cell in the `eActivesheetRange` Range.

Is there a way to call `cells()` using the MATLAB `Range.Value` connection? Would `cells().Value` be able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think [writing to Excel using ActiveX](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-matlab-application-as-an-automation-client.html) is able to handle [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) types properly. In this case, you can make it work by simply converting your string array into a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of [character vectors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) using [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html). Changing your last line of code to the following works for me (in R2016b):

```
eActivesheetRange.Value = cellstr(A);
```

Replacing the last two lines with the following also works:

```
e.Activesheet.Range('A1:A3').Value = cellstr(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is of course, a `for` loop.

```
   alphacolumn=char(97:117);

% iterate through data array

for i=1:21
        str=string(alphacolumn(i))+2;
        str2=string(alphacolumn(i))+202;
        write1=char(str+":"+str2);
   if ~isreal(tsc{i,1})
        T = (tsc{i,1});
for j = 1:length(T)
        rrange = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.Range(char(string(alphacolumn(i)) + string(j+1)));
            xlcompatiblestring1 = char(string(T(j,:,:)));
    rrange.Value= xlcompatiblestring1;

end
   else
        tsci=tsc{i,1};            
% write data to xl target file
        %xlswrite(xlfilepath,tsci,write1);
        xlActivesheetRange = get(xl.Activesheet,'Range',write1);
        xlActivesheetRange.Value = tsci;
   end
end
```

Comment: Hopefully this will help someone who's stuck. Please comment if you know a better way!